# Android SQLite Query Where and Where

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, where-clause

I need to return the ID value from the database where dan == table_column_one and where vrijeme == table_column_two. I don't know how to do this.

```
public static int returnID(String dan, int vrijeme){
        Cursor cursor;
        int IDRQ;
        cursor = db.query
                (
                        TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[] { TABLE_COLUMN_ID, TABLE_COLUMN_ONE, TABLE_COLUMN_TWO },                       
                        new String[] {TABLE_COLUMN_ONE + " like " + "'%" + dan + "%'", TABLE_COLUMN_TWO + " like " + "'%" + vrijeme + "%'"}, null, null, null, null
                );  
        cursor.moveToFirst();           
        IDRQ = cursor.getInt(0);
        return IDRQ;
    }   );
```

This is how I tried, but of course, its wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SQLiteDatabase.query() the selection comes in two parts. The where clause (a `String`) and the whereArgs (an array of `String`).

To add more than one condition to the where clause you can use `AND` or `OR`, just like `&&` or `||` in Java.

A question mark in the where clause is bound to one of the Strings in the whereArgs array.

```
cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { TABLE_COLUMN_ID, TABLE_COLUMN_ONE, TABLE_COLUMN_TWO },
TABLE_COLUMN_ONE + " LIKE ? AND " + TABLE_COLUMN_TWO + " LIKE ?",                           
new String[] {"%" + dan + "%", "%" + vrijeme + "%"},
null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, a little bit complicated don't you think? At least when you try it for the first time.

Comment: @alex what if you actually need multiple where clauses? Couldnt find anything about it (on the same table) like: 
where type ='A' and value='Hello' and where type='B' and value='Goodbye'
The problem with above query: The type column has different values and I need to check for different type/value column combinations.