# Quering SqlLite database using clause in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am getting an error in the below query.

The error is it does not find the type string.

What is wrong with my query ?

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE " + KEY_TYPE + " ='" + type + "'";
```

My Log cat
My Log Cat 02-14 16:33:17.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: type: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Mycontacts WHERE type ='whitelist'

Full query code

```
public List<Contacts> getAllphContacts(String type) {
        List<Contacts> contactList = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
        // Select All Query

        //String selectQuery =  "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS +KEY_TYPE + "=?";                //*tried this also  
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE " + KEY_TYPE + " ="+ type; //***this also not working
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contacts contact = new Contacts();
                contact.setphid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));             
                contact.setphname(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setphnumber(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.settype(cursor.getString(3));//********For whiteList*********//

                // Adding contact to list
              contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
```

Comment: Post some more code, please!

Comment: Check this Link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594716/android-sqlite-query-where-and-where

Answer (score -1):

```
    String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Cart Where id=" + id";
cursor = data.selectQuery(QUERY);
int count = cursor.getCount();

if (count <= 0) {
/// insert
}else{

/// update
}
```

Comment: This does not help with the problem `no such column: type`.