# Android sqlite create WHERE clause which includes OR

Tags: android

I know how to create a single where clause using:

```
db.query("table",
    new String[] {"SUM(column1)"}, 
    "column2 = ?",
    new String[] {"1"}, null, null, null);
```

But how do I include an OR clause in this? Primarily, I want to return data where the column value equals 1 OR 2.

Also, is there any advantage to using `query()` over `rawQuery()`?

Thanks in advance, Dan.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15594770

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use **in** to indicate the value of column2

```
db.query("table",
new String[] {"SUM(column1)"}, 
"column2 in(?,?)",
new String[] {"1","2"}, null, null, null);
```

`query` is a capsulation for us without writing sql statement directly,it can reduce handwriting-mistake,but it's efficiency maybe slower than use `rawQuery`,
`rawQuery` let us use sql and pass some parameter to replace **?** of last sql,but it maybe cause sql injection,however if you can promise the sql will be executed by yourself only,you need't to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the well detailed information. I have decided to go with rawQuery, as for me it is more efficient. All I simply need to do is: `rawQuery("SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table WHERE column2 = 2 OR column2 = 4")` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns our the rawQuery function is the easiest for me. I can insert exact SQL by using: `rawQuery("SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table WHERE column2 = 2 OR column2 = 4")`